# PHP function question

Tags: php, function

I don't now if this is the place to ask this kind of question so I will give it a try. I was wondering what does the following php user defined function do in the code example below? If someone explain it to me in detail thanks.

```
function decode_characters($info)
{
    $info = mb_convert_encoding($info, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $info = preg_replace('~^(&([a-zA-Z0-9]);)~',htmlentities('${1}'),$info);
    return($info);
}
```

Comment: I was just asking a question because I was wondering what does it do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The function is a little odd. The first function call transforms a string encoded in UTF-8 to an ASCII encoded string where the non-mapped characters are converted to HTML entities (named entities if they exist in HTML 4, otherwise numeric entities). For instance:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("foo\"é⌑'&", "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

yields

```
foo"&eacute;&#8977;'&
```

So this differs from htmlentities in that 1) numerical entities are used in the circumstances given and 2) special characters such as `&`, `"` or `<` are not touched.

The second function call, however, is more strange. It finds if a named entity with only one ASCII alphanumeric character starts the input, and, if so, <del>calls `htmlentities` on this input</del> (actually it doesn't because the `e` modifier is not used and the function name is not in a string, so it's executed when the arguments are evaluated). This call has no effect because `htmlentities('${1}')` is `'${1}'` and the backreference 1 encompasses the whole match, so, even if the expression matches, there's no substitution.